# jQuery code breaking other code

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm using this function to keep a div on the screen when the page is scrolled down. This work fine, however it seem to break some other jQuery code (in the wordpress). The problem is with the following function. If i remove it, other code works fine. Can someone suggest what can be problem with following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    jQuery.event.add(window, "scroll", showbar);
    var sharebar = jQuery('#showbar');
    var start = jQuery(sharebar).offset().top;
        function showbar() {
            var p = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            jQuery(sharebar).css('position',((p+10)>start) ? 'fixed' : 'absolute');
            jQuery(sharebar).css('top',((p+10)>start) ? '10px' : '');
        }   
});
```

Edit: What I meant by 'breaking the code' was that, if i include a javascript having this code in my wordpress theme. The javascript of the wordpress will not work in the control panel of the theme (eg. no lightbox popup by clicking the image upload button etc). The wordpress controls will start working as soon as i remove this code. So obviously theres something wrong with this code.

**Edit 2:**

I dont seem to get any js errors but i noticed if i wrap the code in `(function() { .. })();` instead of `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`   then the wordpress does not have any problem, but then my code does not work. Can you suggest how can i use function() instead of jQuery(document).ready.. Sorry but i dont have much knowledge of jquery.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what 'other code' is or what 'break' is.

Comment: How does it "break"? What errors are you getting? Have you tried to debug this (FireBug/Chrome JS Debugger/ etc.)?

Comment: Seems like generally these questions lead to the inevitable question, do you know how to debug?  http://getfirebug.com/javascript

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: Have you looked at the error console or debug console to see if there are javascript errors being reported?  The most likely situation is that this code introduces a JS error that prevents other code from running.

Comment: @Caimen: some of us are working on corporate computers and aren't allowed to install software at our own discretion.

Comment: @mblase75 - if he's allowed to inject JS code into the theme, but not allowed to install the necessary tools to debug it, the corporation has larger problems than just this code snippet.

Comment: gdcc: Just because the corporation has a problem doesn't mean they're going to do anything about it.

Comment: There is no overt error in your code. The problem has to be either a variable / namespace collision, or a race condition of some sort. Either way, it's your code conflicting with the wordpress code.

Comment: @mblase75 I was simply pointing to one of many tools meant to help the debug process.  I was simply implying that understanding the debug process goes a long long way.  Corporate problems are not stackoverflow's problem, those problems go here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your second edit, try putting the `(function() { ... })()` closure at the very bottom of your file, just above the closing `</body>` tag. That way, all the relevant DOM elements will already exist.

Comment: thanks ! it worked perfectly. Just wondering if there's any alternative approach (instead of loading at the end of page, loading in header).

Comment: There might be; it's hard to say without seeing the other javascript that yours is clashing with. But it's a pretty standard development practice to put your JS at the bottom of the file, sometimes it's even preferred. Read http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/ for more details on this.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of that piece of code, and add the following CSS rule:

```
#showbar {
    position: fixed;
}
```

This is an universal way to keep an element at the same position, even when the user scrolls. The CSS method requires less computing power than the JavaScript implementation.

If you still want to use JQuery, check this page: http://wpapi.com/wordpress-and-jquery-conflicts-how-to-solve-that/

Answer (score 0):

Your way of creating the `scroll` event is pretty nonstandard. Instead of:

```
jQuery.event.add(window, "scroll", showbar);
```

why don't you try:

```
jQuery(window).bind('scroll', showbar);
```

There's a chance that might solve your issue.